Where is every cubesat I need to scan in Lone Echo?
In the Lone Echo VR game, there are some cubesats (drones, essentially) you need to scan for an optional side mission. 
There are 2 at the depleted dig site, 6 at the main (I think that's what it's called) dig site, 5(?) in the Kronos II interior, and 9 in the Kronos II exterior. There may be a couple more locations, but I'm not sure.
Where is every cubesat in the game? And what happens when you scan all of them?

In the first edition of this question, I accidentally called the game lost-echo. Oops.
